# Receiving error on building an Alpine image on my M1 Macbook

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, apple-m1

When I build my Dockerfile image on my Macbook M1, I begin to receive errors in regards to `syslinux` specifically, and if I were to comment this out I continue to receive errors such as this:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: UNTRUSTED signature
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: UNTRUSTED signature
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: No such file or directory
```

So I know the issue revolves around my repositories that I use so this is where I have the `ENTRYPOINT` say this in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT /src/aports/scripts/mkimage.sh \
    --tag v3.13 \
    --outdir /build \
    --arch x86_64 \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main \
    --extra-repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community \
    --profile iot
```

I would believe this would work on my M1 but it doesn't! I used other another Macbook and that builds it but why not the M1? I would greatly appreciate any help in this.

EDIT 2: Adding full Dockerfile:

```
# This image contains the build environment for edge appliance install ISOs
FROM alpine:3.13

# Define metadata
LABEL maintainer="this_dude@dude.net"

# Configure user
RUN addgroup root this_build

# Initialize update and upgrade on Alpine AMI
RUN apk -U upgrade

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    alpine-conf \
    alpine-sdk \
    apk-tools \
    dosfstools \
    grub-efi \
    mtools \
    squashfs-tools \
    syslinux \
    xorriso

WORKDIR /src

# Clone alpine ports repository containing the iso builder
RUN git clone --depth=1 --branch v3.13.2 git://git.alpinelinux.org/aports
RUN chmod +x aports/scripts/mkimage.sh

# Include edge appliance image profile
RUN ln -sf /build/mkimg.run.sh /src/aports/scripts/mkimg.run.sh

WORKDIR /build

# Run ISO build
ENTRYPOINT /src/aports/scripts/mkimage.sh \
    --tag v3.13 \
    --outdir /build \
    --arch x86_64 \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main \
    --extra-repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community \
    --profile iot
```

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile or at least your parent image. I'm pretty sure that it's all about the thing that you are on the different architecture. So you need to fetch `arm64` not `x86_64`.

Comment: Sure, let me add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=syslinux the `syslinux` bootloader package has not support for `aarch64` (M1 processors). I would suggest to use another bootloader with AMD and ARM support - for example https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=u-boot&branch=edge.

And don't forget to change that `--arch x86_64` argument in your entrypoint to `--arch aarch64` if you want to run it without errors on your M1 processor. Or just remove it to use `default_arch` from the sh script.